# Omit explicit cast for typedefed structures

Tags: c, casting, header, typedef

I'd like to hide the OpenSSL `RSA` structure requirement form my API header so I did:

```
// api.h

typedef struct RSA_key * RSA_key_ptr;

RSA_key_ptr get_rsa_key();
void free_rsa_key(RSA_key_ptr key);
```

```
// api.c

#include <openssl\rsa.h> // RSA struct

typedef RSA RSA_key;

RSA_key_ptr get_rsa_key()
{
  //return RSA_new();
    return (RSA_key_ptr)RSA_new();
}

void free_rsa_key(RSA_key_ptr key)
{
  //RSA_free(key);
    RSA_free((RSA*)key);
}
```

My problem is that every single time I refer to a `RSA` pointer in `api.c` I need to do casts to `RSA*` from `RSA_key_ptr` to prevent ***incompatible pointer types*** warnings.

I'd like to find more elegant way to:

1. Avoid explicit casts
2. Avoid warnings

Comment: Why would you wanna avoid explicit casts? They add readability.

Comment: @Fredrik Hmm, I thought that it actually decreases the readability (at least for me, but ofc. as a code author, I'm not the best person to judge).

Comment: Explicit casts like these only serve to hide bugs or design faults in the program. Instead of casting, you need to fix the bug/design fault. In addition, hiding pointers behind typedefs is very bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a cast. `struct RSA_key` is a new type, and is not defined by `typedef RSA RSA_key;`. It's the name of an unrelated structure without a definition. You can only deal in pointers to it, and cast other structure pointers to and from it.

It's not a bad technique at hiding implementation details (barring the superfluous `typedef RSA RSA_key;`). And the cast is good standard C.

If you find yourself in situations where the cast expressions require too many parentheses around itself, then a small utility function or macro can potentially help mitigate it:

```
static inline RSA* as_rsa(struct RSA_key* rsa_key)
{ return (RSA*)rsa_key; }

static inline struct RSA_key* as_rsa_key(RSA* rsa_key)
{ return (struct RSA_key*)rsa_key; }
```